# Unmet dependencies grub-common

Tags: grub2, package-management, dependencies

I'm currently unable to do anything with apt-get due to "unmet dependencies". I have no idea how to start fixing this. The output of

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 grub-efi-amd64 : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2)
 grub-efi-amd64-bin : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2)
 grub2-common : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  grub-common
Suggested packages:
  multiboot-doc grub-emu xorriso desktop-base
The following packages will be upgraded:
  grub-common
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 76 not to upgrade.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,707 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 241896 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Failed to stop grub-common.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status grub-common.service' for details.
Failed to get load state of grub-common.service: Connection timed out
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Failed to stop grub-common.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status grub-common.service' for details.
Failed to get load state of grub-common.service: Connection timed out
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Failed to start grub-common.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status grub-common.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

I also get a timeout when I execute

```
systemctl status grub-common.service
```

As follows:

```
Failed to get properties: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out a restart and an upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

was all I needed.

I actually ended up not being able to restart. Something weird with the running services not responding(?!). I ended up rage quitting with the power button and it seems that's all I needed to do. Hope this helps someone.